# Free memory after using sql server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, t-sql, ssis, sql-server-2017

Is there any way to free memory after using sql server. I don't know why it doesn't doing itself

Screen From Manager

[image]

I have this problem after using Visual Studio with SSIS to LookUp

Answer (score 0):

The memory manager will release memory when the OS "asks" for it. Stop trying to micro manage your instance. And task manager is not an accurate way to measure memory in a server instance.